# What's the difference between Google Analytics API client libraries? (google-api-dotnet-client vs. google-gdata)

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-analytics-api

What is the difference between the [Google APIs Client Library for .NET](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) (google-api-dotnet-client) and [.NET library for the Google Data API](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/)  (google-gdata) as they pertain to the [Google Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both linked to from google "Core Reporting API" pages.
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/gdataLibraries.html

One is linked under v3.0, and one from v2.4.

The .net library for v3.0 still appears to be in beta.

There is a comparison between v3.0 and v2.4 here: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html

Comment: Yes but it seems that for 2.4 and 3.0 you speak about same project : http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/ but what is this project : http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/ ?

Comment: There are versions 2.4 and 3.0 of the Core Reporting API http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html, 2.4 links to the code http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/ (Current version 1.9). Version 3.0 of the Core Reporting API links to http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

Comment: Ah ok fine! so next we will have to use code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client and the other library will be depracated ?

Comment: Unsure when the older version will be depreciated, guess should be a while, as new one isn't backward compatible, .net client is still in beta and there's no samples included for GA for .net client.

Comment: I am also looking for GA .net client example of v3.
I have to use Core reporting API to show some reports.

Answer (score 4):

In my (limited) experience:

- GData has a better integrated OAuth2 support, which is easier to use.
- GoogleApiDotnetClient services return specific subtypes while GData returns base types. For example, a GoogleApiDotnetClient calendar events request returns something typed `IEnumerable<Event>`, while GData returns an `IEnumerable<AtomEntry>` where each instance is actually an `EventEntry`.
- GoogleApiDotnetClient instances are simpler, for example an `Event.Summary` is a string field whereas GData's Summary is an `AtomTextConstruct` which has a `Text` property.
- GoogleApiDotnetClient does not support some APIs, notably Spreadsheets.
- The dates tend to be strings in GoogleApiDotnetClient but proper `DateTime` values in GData.
- Neither has any XML comments whatsoever, sadly.

So far I have a preference for GoogleApiDotnetClient, but frankly, both of them have lots of space for improvement.

Comment: What you are saying is very interesting. But why to maintain the two library? are they all officials?

Comment: @Dragouf I get the impression that only GData is official, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides a .Net wrapper for those who prefer/need to code their application in .Net:

> http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/
>
> The GData .NET Client Library provides a library and source code that
>   make it easy to access data through Google Data APIs.

PS:

Google Data (GData) != Google Analytics API:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/

Comment: thanks I know. But I wonder about the difference between the two projects. Are they all officials ? What is the difference between two of us? I'm actually using gdata API but I wonder if I can use the second one and which is the best.

Answer (score 0):

**(Sep 2020)** Pretty much all other answers are now out-of-date (including any `code.google.com` links). [GData APIs](http://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory) are the previous generation of Google APIs, and old GData Docs API documentation is getting harder to find. While not all GData APIs have been deprecated, [all **newer** Google APIs](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis) do **not** use [the Google Data protocol](http://developers.google.com/gdata). For Analytics specifically, Google didn't just release a new API, but [an entire **family** of APIs](http://developers.google.com/analytics), none of which are GData.

In order to use the new APIs linked to above, you need to get [the Google APIs Client Library for .NET/C#](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet), then choose which API(s) you want to use. Overall, developers get a more powerful & flexible experience & functionality than older API releases. Finally, each API should have their own code samples to help get you kickstarted. If you still need the docs for the old APIs (Reporting API v2 & v3), they're available at the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting).